# Webserver not working

Tags: apache2

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I have installed apache2, but the problem is when I visit my IP as site in order to view web files, it says unable to connect.

If I try to restart apache in SSH I get this error;

```
~# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                               
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using (IP address of my server here). 
Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

EDIT: here is the error log as suggested by user

[Pastebin to error log](http://pastebin.com/qcjU1N2z)

Does someone know the solution?

Comment: The mentioned error is not the reason for the problem. Paste the contents (or at least the last 20-100 lines) of the error log here, so people trying to help will have a better idea of what might be causing this problem.  The path to the log file is /var/log/apache2/error.log (if the location hasn't been changed in the config file).

Comment: Added error log; http://pastebin.com/qcjU1N2z

Comment: I can't see anything unusual in the log file... Are you sure you're accessing the site by the right combination of IP and port, and that there are no firewall rules blocking the access to the webserver?

Comment: Do a `sudo netstat -tulpn` the check if your defined port (e.g. 80/443) is opened and accessible from other hosts (must look like e.g. `0.0.0.0:80` or `:::80` respectively with `443`).

Comment: Hello i am inexperienced with ubuntu. I have just received server and updated, then i typed apt-get install apache2 ...but it's not working for some reason, i don't know why, the ip combination is 100% correct.... Did sudo netstat -tulpn and that is the result http://gyazo.com/ba1f3660306883a58aa7e7c6efc03c06

Comment: Does anything happen when you do `wget http://localhost` on the server? You should see a file being downloaded.

Comment: yes, it shows index.html saved

Comment: i asked support for help....we'll see

Comment: If the wget-command works, the web server  itself is running. You just can't access the server from the client. The could be caused by network (routing, firewall, proxy, etc.) or by web server configuration (only access from specific hosts/adresses like localhost).

Answer (score 1):

There was nothing wrong with the webserver's configuration. Instead, it was user error -- I was trying to visit `https://` instead of `http://`.